# Perform an operation automatically based on date. Php /Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am doing a library project for my college. in that, i have table called 'tbl_reserve' for store reservations. Structure is

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbtUt.jpg)
There are two date fields to store reservation date and expiry date. 'reserve_status' shows is it 'Reserved/Expired'.

is there is any way to automatic change the value of 'reserve_status' field after expiry date.

i am using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Would the situation allow you to calculate it on the fly?  Basically, if the current date is between from and to, it's still an active reservation.  Or are you needing to mark it such for some other reason?

Comment: Yes. it can calculate on the fly. but there are too many records. i thought status fields save some time in executing queries.

Comment: How exactly is this data being used?  If you're not pulling large recordsets, on the fly would be fine.  If you are trying to pull by status though, then you would probably want to precalculate it (particularly if you were only using the status as a filter, and no other where conditions).

Comment: Approx. 500/per day request for this page.

Comment: The number of requests is not what I'm curious about.  I'm curious about what conditions you're pulling the data on.  Are you pulling reserves of the currently logged in user or what?

Comment: user can view their reservations (All records of active and last ten records of expired) in their member profile. after login, members are redirect to their profile page.

Comment: Since you have the user id column being filtered before the date calculation would be done, you would likely be able to do it on the fly with minimal performance impact.  Nothing wrong with pre-updating it either though :p.

Comment: Thanks Corbin for your suggestion. :)

Comment: No problem.  Just thought I would offer an alternate approach :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can for example run a process at some fixed interval to check if the reservation has expired this can be done with [Cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for example.

Another way is to check for expiry every time the table is accessed for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

I would just check if you want to add a new reservation if the old one is expired and remove it then. You could also run a cronjob which check all rows and deletes expired rows.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to use cronjobs to achieve this problem.